# Typescript: Get length of custom typed array

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

Can somebody tell me how to get array length of custom typed array?

E.g:

```
type TMyArray = IProduct[]

interface IProduct {
  cost: number,
  name: string,
  weight: number
}
```

So, how to get length here:

```
const testArr: TMyArray = [...some array elements]

console.log(testArr.length) // returning type error Property 'length' does not exist on type 'IDocument'
```

Main question is how to do it right with typescript

I've tried to add length to `IProduct`, but it seems wrong

```
interface IProduct = {
  cost: number,
  name: string,
  weight: number,
  length: number,
}
```

Comment: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAKgsiAggJ2QQxFAvFAkgBWQHsATAVwGNgBtAXQCh6BLAO2AmQDM0LoDjyVKAG96UKBSIBnYAC4oLMgFsARhwA0YhWiUR5M5KwDmm8QHcITIwAs5C5WuT0Avo0ksZUdjJTJ58JFQMbChqLVFxcUkZeQBGU0iWHT0oAHJY1ITzSxs7WK1nBIjI6LsAJiztXXlUssytbKtbeTKC+gZ6dykiABsIADoeoiMACm9gX0GIFiNgawBKeiA I cannot replicate your issue? - The code also doesn't include the type `IDocument`

Comment: @evolutionxbox it helps, you helped me found, that i'm forgot to use [] on type declaration

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest using, as type for testArr, an actual Array with its contents as generic.

`const testArr: Array<IProduct> = [...some array elements]`

This way, the whole thing works on aforementioned playground https://www.typescriptlang.org/play :

```
interface IProduct {
  cost: number,
  name: string,
  weight: number
}

const testArr: Array<IProduct> = []

console.log(testArr.length)
```

Edit: Oh, now I'm confused; your code works there, too, and why shouldn't it ... hmmm ...

Comment: It's ok. Thank you. I found out, that my mistake was not to add [] to IProduct

Answer (score 0):

The declaration of your interface is incorrect. It does not need a `=` sign. So, it should be:

```
interface IProduct {
  cost: number,
  name: string,
  weight: number,
  length: number,
}
```

- Example: [TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/PTAEHUFMBsGMHsC2lQBd5oBYoCoE8AHSAZVgCcBLA1UABWgEM8BzM%20AVwDsATAGiwoBnUENANQAd0gAjQRVSQAUCEmYKsTKGYUAbpGF4OY0BoadYKdJMoL%20gzAzIoz3UNEiPOofEVKVqAHSKymAAmkYI7NCuqGqcANag8ABmIjQUXrFOKBJMggBcISGgoAC0oACCbvCwDKgU8JkY7p7ehCTkVDQS2E6gnPCxGcwmZqDSTgzxxWWVoASMFmgYkAAeRJTInN3ymj4d-jSCeNsMq-wuoPaOltigAKoASgAywhK7SbGQZIIz5VWCFzSeCrZagNYbChbHaxUDcCjJZLfSDbExIAgUdxkUBIursJzCFJtXydajBVDtbwAWTwFTIZCYoAAvKAAJK0NjcdiwVAAbQAusEMgoyMkGEt2ZzuTQAN6KEoAIgQglQCvy-XYiGk3148tACs4DGQaquqEonGYusVUgozEwqvVnE12rIigAvsEEJwVWh9Kg6WR1TgaQHGSzeTLlah1QBGfiG5DqgDk6HQSf4Nrt0dAAFY3YLFF7BPB3AFoPBmAAKBQqgNllHMWIASmCKhwzQ8ZC8iHgfQYwPYNC%20bjMzHYDGYkH4sGg6kS-fgehEXgVAFFVkaFvoFUlsQrwA5UEnhAA5SASBVBFQAeS%20ZHeginWkgR1QjgUrmkeFATh7OmGWD6CgCCINCwiXMOEi9tEIgGBw2ILEwrAcDwQQlEAA)
- [Interface documentation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html)

Comment: Surely if this was the issue the OP wouldn't be getting the error _"type error Property 'length' does not exist on type 'IDocument'"_?

Comment: Thx, I'm fixed equals, but thats was only mistake for stackoverflow, and not resolving my problem

Comment: In that case, it seems correct.